# How do I check collision between a ball of various speeds and a paddle

Tags: c

I'm currently creating a game for a university assignment which is similar to pong. To give you a rough idea of how the game works, there's a single paddle at the bottom of the screen which moves horizontally. There is also a ball which will move around the screen and the player has to stop the ball from going off the bottom of the screen by using the paddle. Everytime the ball hits the top of the screen the player scores a point.

I've managed to get the majority of the game working but I'm having some problems with the collisions between the ball and the paddle. Currently the collision works fine if the ball is moving at a speed of 1 pixel per frame. However for the specification the ball speed must be variable and therefore the ball needs to be able to collide correctly with the paddle at all speeds.

The code I'm currently using for the collisions is as follows:

```
if((ball.y+5) == (bat.y))
    {
        if(ball.x >= bat.x && ball.x <= (bat.x+40))
        {
            ball.dy = -ball.dy;
            game.goingUp = true;
        }
    }
```

Essentially this tests whether or not the ball's coordinates are equal to the coordinates of the paddle, and will change the ball's direction if this is true. However due to this having specific coordinates, the ball may pass through the bat entirely at higher speeds.

What I want to do is make this collision work at speeds up to 10 pixels per frame, but I'm really not sure how to do this, any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: You could assess the game at `x` times the rate, where `x` is the ball speed in pixels per frame, and only refresh the output image every `x` frames.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution to this is what they call sweeping. Take the last position and the current position, create a line (or a larger rectangle if your doing more complex objects), then do collision checks with that.

It should be noted that anything larger than a pixel can be represented as bounding boxes, which are rectangles or circles, relatively simply.

Comment: So I've created a trail behind the moving ball, which extends about 5 pixels behind the current position of the ball. How do I now use this to test collisions with in terms of my current collision code which is above?

Comment: @Ajek You can test every single pixel and on detection make the reaction on the actual pixel. Generally the last position doesn't need to be visible, but is rather stored in the moving object, but your solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what my first, ugly solution would be (to get my creative juices flowing).  I haven't tested it, though, and I doubt its accuracy.

Using **>=** will tell you if you would have collided (assuming you were lined up in the x-axis at the time):

```
if((ball.y+5) >= (bat.y)
```

Then there's only the issue of handling how far left and right you would have been at the time of the collision.  If you keep track of how far you moved along the x-axis you could try to estimate where you would have been when (ball.y+5) == bat.y.  Perhaps something like:

```
// Assuming this is how you keep track of your old position:
int x_difference = ball.x - ball.last_x;
int y_difference = ball.y - ball.last_y;

float percent = (bat.y - (ball.last_y+5)) / float(y_difference); // how far through your last move were you when you crossed the bat's y position
int x_at_collision = ball.x + (percent * x_difference);
```

And now you can modify your other line:

```
if(x_at_collision >= bat.x && x_at_collision <= (bat.x+40))
```